# Error "Missing '}' or object member name" in Google SDTT

Tags: json, json-ld

I've below JSON LD data:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org", 
  "@type": "NewsArticle", 
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "http://healthypets.mercola.com/sites/healthypets/archive/2017/01/25/dog-foods-contain-high-fluoride-levels.aspx"
  },
  "headline": "80 Percent of Tested Dog Foods Contain High Fluoride Levels", 
  "datePublished": "2017-01-25T12:00:00Z", 
  "dateModified": "1/18/2017 7:28:27 PM", 
  "description": "A study found that 8 out of 10 dog food brands contained fluoride 2.5 times higher than the EPA national drinking water standard.", 
  "author": { 
      "@type": "Person", 
      "name": "Dr. Becker", 
  },
  "publisher": { 
      "@type": "Organization", 
      "name": "Mercola.com", 
      "logo": { 
          "@type": "ImageObject", 
          "url": "http://media.mercola.com/themes/healthypets/images/healthypets-logo-responsive.png", 
          "width": 600, 
          "height": 60 
      }
  }, 
  "image": { 
      "@type": "ImageObject", 
      "url": "http://media.mercola.com/themes/healthypets/images/healthypets-logo-responsive.png", 
      "width": 2000,
      "height": 800 
  }
}
</script>
```

Please see below error:

[image: Google SDTT output]

I get the error stating that

> Missing '}' or object member name.

Comment: Not sure if it accepts the `,` at the end of `author` object (followed by `}`). Did you check the format in a JSON parser ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `,` from the last key of `author` object

```
"author": { 
  "@type": "Person", 
  "name": "Dr. Becker", 
},
```

should be

```
"author": { 
  "@type": "Person", 
  "name": "Dr. Becker"
},
```

You can test your JSON-LD on http://json-ld.org/playground/

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma from 14th line in `author` object property  `"name": "Dr. Becker",`

Like only `"name": "Dr. Becker"`